# How to show message if none of radio button selected in c# windows application

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I'm fresher and I'm trying to implement gender property logic. I have three radio buttons
male, female and others. If I not select any of the radio button it should throw me an error message. First time it is giving message but second time even I select radio button it is showing same message. Please help me on this. thanks in advance.

**Here is my code.**

```
 private void btnadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       else if (!rbmale.Checked || !rbfemale.Checked || !rbothers.Checked)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select gender ", "Error");
            return;

        }
```

Comment: Why have you used an `else if` with no other conditions? Surely you just want `if`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're checking it wrong way so consider this right logic for your desired output.

```
private void btnadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!rbmale.Checked && !rbfemale.Checked && !rbothers.Checked)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please select gender ", "Error");
        return;

    }
```

> **By writing like**
>
> ```
> !rbmale.Checked || !rbfemale.Checked || !rbothers.Checked
> ```
>
> **You're checking that all radio buttons should be checked and hence it is showing you error everytime even if you check any one of the
>   radio button.**

You should check that if none of them is checked then only it should give you error message and it is the correct logic for such functionality.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

It should be like

```
!rbmale.Checked && !rbfemale.Checked && !rbothers.Checked
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also write something like

```
if (!(rbmale.Checked || rbfemale.Checked || rbothers.Checked))
{
}
```

Comment: consider checking my answer. You'd get actual problem in OP's question. What he is doing is not wrong but actual logic of OP is wrong. :)

Comment: Thanks for the response

Answer (score 0):

Guessing that Chirag has the answer that you are looking for but there are many ways to check if all the values are false. Here are some alternatives:

```
if (!rbmale.Checked & !rbfemale.Checked & !rbothers.Checked)
{
}

if (new[] {rbmale.Checked,rbfemale.Checked,rbothers.Checked}.All(x => !x))
{
}

if (!rbmale.Checked || !rbfemale.Checked || !rbothers.Checked)
{      

}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Please select gender ", "Error");
    return;
}
```